# Force on rope with accelerating mass on pulley

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, acceleration

I have a pretty basic pulley problem where I lack the right start.

A child sits on a seat which is held by a rope going to a cable roll (attached to a tree) and back into the kid's hands.

[Sketch http://wstaw.org/m/2011/11/08/m7.png](http://wstaw.org/m/2011/11/08/m7.png)

When it sits still, I believe that the force on either side of the rope must be equal to keep is static, therefore each rope holds $\frac{1}{2}mg$, the cable roll has to carry the full $mg$.

Now, the kid wants go up with $\frac{1}{5}g$. For the whole system to accelerate up, the cable roll has to support another $\frac{1}{5}mg$ resulting in $\frac{6}{5}mg$ of force.

The question that I cannot answer is:

> How much force does the kid need to apply onto the rope in its hands?

As I said before, $F_k$ (kid) and $F_s$ (seat) have to be $\frac{6}{5}mg$. So I get this:

$$F_k + F_s = \frac{6}{5}mg $$

In order to solve for either one, I would need another equation. The forces cannot be equal, otherwise there would be no movement of the rope. So I just invented the condition, that the difference of the forces has to be the acceleration:

$$F_k - F_s = \frac{1}{5}mg $$

I can solve this giving me $F_s = \frac{5}{10}mg$ and $F_k = \frac{7}{10}mg$ which will sum up to the total force.

But is this the right approach at all?

Comment: You should think of the fact, that the kid has to pull the double length of rope than someone standing on ground had to pull.

Comment: So since someone else would have to pull $6/5 \cdot mg$, the kid would have to pull half of that, being $3/5 \cdot mg$? Then the force on either side of the rope is equal, it that correct?

Comment: Is there any way to include a crude sketch here. I am having trouble visualizing the problem.

Comment: A diagram would be very helpful.

Comment: Added a sketch based on Doresoom's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is easier seen with a free body diagram. You'll need 2 equations, so use two points on the rope: one attached to the seat, and one where the kid holds the rope.

For the first, you've got the weight of the kid `mg` pulling downward, the force `F` the kid is exerting on the rope upward, (since he's lightening the load on the seat by effectively distributing his weight elsewhere) and the tension `T` in the rope pulling upward equal to `ma`:

$$T + F -mg = ma $$

The second FBD gives you the tension in the rope pulling upward, and the force the kid is exerting pulling downward. Since it's a weightless point, the `ma` portion is zero:

$$ T - F = 0$$

Combining and simplifying:

$$ 2F - mg = \frac{1}{5}mg $$
$$ 2F = \frac{6}{5}mg $$
$$ F = \frac{3}{5}mg $$

Of course, this is assuming the rope has no weight per unit length, and there is no friction in the drum.

Comment: I went ahead and gave a full solution to this since you had already posted the correct answer yourself.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the tension, that clears it up a lot. I created a diagram with your forces in it.

Comment: To the "no friction"-part: Yes, and the inertia (rotation) of the roll can be neglected as well.

Comment: You still need to add F acting upward on the kid, since he's exerting F down on the other end of the rope.

Comment: I thought that the tension on the rope on the right side would be the opposing force against the pull of the kid.

Comment: Think of it this way: If you stand next to a table and push downward on the table with your hands, the floor under your feet will be holding up your weight minus the weight you place on the table. So the tension on the rope (seat side) is holding up the kid's weight minus the weight he places on the other side of the rope.

Answer (score 0):

The kid pulls himself, so there are two tensions 2T to support his body:

```
         2T-mg=(1/5)mg
```

so
                T=(3/5)mg

The force the kid applied equals the normal force n exerted by the seat, therefore

```
             T+n-mg=ma  

             n=mg-T+ma=mg-(3/5)mg+(1/5)mg=(3/5)mg
```

Comment: We do have [MathJax enabled](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on this site, so you can use Latex-like mark-up to produce equations.